# Android Update listview with notifyDataSetChanged does not work

Tags: android, listview

My list view is not updated and I have follwed some of the suggestions on stackOverflow but nothing have helped. Please help me with this:)
I'm doing this within a mainListView.setOnItemClickListener.

```
            listAdapter.clear();
            //listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.simplerow, arrayView);
            listAdapter.addAll(arrayView);
            mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //mainListView.invalidateViews();
            //mainListView.refreshDrawableState();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hell I feel stupid:)
This was not the fault. This code is correct or it anyway does the trick for me.

In short: If you looking for nothing and try to apply nothing into the arrayView you got what??? NOTHING!!! SO what was the point of updating that if I had nothing.

My bad...sorry:)